# To learn English, How do i make a plan for my English?

Tags: questions

To learn English, How do I make a plan for my English?
In deed, the moment that I use English is just when i do StackExchange and study my major. I want to study English in habit. For that, What should I have to start from the beginning?

Comment: Read as much as you can, write as much as you can, and find someone to talk to.

Comment: More info is necessary: what is your major? What is your native language? How old are you? Where do you live (city, country)? How many languages do you know? What are they? How did you acquire them? Is English spoken as a second or foreign language where you live? Do you know anybody that speaks English that you can practice with?  Why do you want to learn English? What kind of resources do you have (this includes current possession and/or ability to acquire things such as textbooks, Skype access)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing that you need to focus on is listening, just like you did with your native language when you were a child, the first thing that you started with was listening. You need also to listen to things that are interesting to you, so you stay motivated and avoid getting board and quit.

You can read also, and the same as for listening, you need to read what is interesting to you.

You can start to speak with native speakers or other learners if you want.

And the most important thing is that you need to have a very strong "**why?**" of learning English, this is very important for you to stay motivated and improve quickly.